# CakePHP: Relationship Questions

Tags: php, cakephp, relationships

I have a problem determining relationships for my first CakePHP project. I am trying to build a Backpacking Gear List Management system. Here are my tables:

**Gear -** Each gear item is in one category, but can be in many gear lists, but is user specific.

**Categories -** Category for the above gear items. Categories are unique.

**Gear List -** Each gear list can be assigned to many different trips, and is user specific. Once an item is added to this list, it cannot be added again.

**Trips -** Each trip has a single Gear List. Each trip is unique.

**Users -** Each user has their own items, categories, gear lists, and trips.

My problem, what model should I have in place for the Gear lists, and what relationship should I use? Should there be a table for Gear List Items that house the data from both tables? How do I go about adding multiple items to a single gear list in the database? Would I need to store multiple item_id in the same row?

The closest example I can think of is a shopping cart. You have items for sale, and you have a cart (gear list). You add items to the cart, and then purchase the cart (assign it to a trip).

Answer (score 0):

Storing multiple foreign keys for the same table on a single record is usually the wrong way to go.

To me it sounds like you are looking for a many-to-many relationship, ie a [hasAndBelongsToMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) association, where `GearList HABTM GearItem` and vice versa (In case you want `GearItem::find()` to return the associated `GearList` records).

The association is stored in a separate join table, that way a `GearItem` can be assigned to many different `GearList`, while a `GearList` can have many different `GearItem`.

See also [Saving Related Model Data (HABTM)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-habtm).

Comment: Do you declare this relationship in both models? I found the information on how to build the join table, so when I add a new GearItem to a GearList, would I write it to the gearitems_gearlists table (join table)? Lastly, it seems as though I would need a GearItem foreign key in the GearList table and vice versa. How will this be possible if it can have multiple Gear lists?

Comment: In case you want `GearItem::find()` to include the associated `GearList`s, then yes, define it for both models. Writing to the join table is done by CakePHP automatically, see [Saving Related Model Data (HABTM)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-habtm).

Comment: @BobHaskett No, you don't need foreign keys in the tables for `GearItem` and `GearList`, it all happens in the join table, where each record will represent an association between a `GearItem` and a `GearList`.